# PHP. why is get_post_meta() returning key not value

Tags: php, wordpress

Fairly new to PHP and WordPress and have a query around the get_post_meta function.

So obviously the function returns the value associated with a key of a particular meta attribute but for some reason I am getting the keys returned.

The meta attribute is a selection box with a few key value pairs shown below:

```
function frontend_add_donation_field( $fields ) {
  $fields['job']['job_donation'] = array(
    'label'       => __( 'Please specify the required donation amount to be paid by the successful applicant upon completion.', 'job_manager' ),
    'type'        => 'select',
    'options' => array('tier1' => 100, 'tier2' => 200, 'tier3' => 300, 'tier4' => 400, 'tier5' => 500, 'tier6' => 600),
    'required'    => true,
    'placeholder' => 'Please Select',
    'priority'    => 5
  );
  return $fields;
}
```

Now the code in the front end at the moment looks like this:

`<h4><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_job_donation', true ); ?></h4>`

What I'm getting returned from this is 'tier1' etc. and not the value associated with it. (I excuse any bad coding at this stage such as escaping html ect. Just trying to get a value at the moment).

Performing a `var_dump(get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_job_donation', true ))` returns `string(5) "tier5"`

Also as per the comments, the values that are being inserted in to the array are:
`array('tier1' => 100, 'tier2' => 200, 'tier3' => 300, 'tier4' => 400, 'tier5' => 500, 'tier6' => 600)`

**Update**
The following horrible HTML gets the desired effect but really is not suitable.

```
<?php $donation_tier = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_job_donation', true );
                $donation = "";
                if ($donation_tier === 'tier1') {
                    $donation = "100";
                }
                else if ($donation_tier === 'tier2') {
                    $donation = "200";
                }
                else if ($donation_tier === 'tier3') {
                    $donation = "300";
                }
                else if ($donation_tier === 'tier4') {
                    $donation = "400";
                }
                else if ($donation_tier === 'tier5') {
                    $donation = "500";
                }
                else if ($donation_tier === 'tier6') {
                    $donation = "600";
                } else {
                    $donation = $donation_tier;
                }
            ?>

            <?php do_action( 'single_job_listing_meta_end' ); ?>

            <li class="meta-important">The successful applicant will need to pay a donation of £<?php echo $donation; ?>  plus an £50 standard fee to Horses 4 Homes upon completion.</li>
```

I think what I need to show is the key of the array element, but not sure if you can get this using the get_post_meta() function.

Is this due to the fact I'm using selection Boxes?? All of my text fields seem to be rendering correctly. Any help would be great.

Comment: All your code does is return an array of values. We can't see what the result of get_post_meta() is or the data your saving to it? Can you var_dump() that please and add it to your question. If all you're getting is tier1 then it could be the way your saving your meta or the way your accessing that options array.

Comment: @AlexKnopp I have updated the question to reflect your comments.

Comment: Thanks for the update. One more thing, it would be good to see the html of your full select element.

Comment: What is your intent with even having "tierX" as the array keys? What's that useful for? I'm not a WordPress expert, but it seems to me that what you're doing here is creating a form element that will show the user numbers like 100, 200, etc., but the data that would be saved from these are tier1, tier2, etc. In other words, in PHP arrays, we call these "key" => "value", but in a select input they are "value" => "name". So it may just be a confusion of the two very different meanings of the word "value" in these two different contexts.

Comment: @AlexKnopp I'm not sure where to find it. It's produced by a WordPress Plugin WP Job Manager. This is half the issue, I'm not a PHP developer and trying to change things. I have had to add some awful code at the moment to get the desired outcome that I will put in the original question.

Comment: @GregSchmidt from my understanding it was how you implemented a selection box using the plugin WP Job Manager for WordPress, though I may be wrong here. I have updated the question with what I think the possible solution should be but just don’t know how to get there.

Comment: Any chance you can supply a URL? We need to see what's coming out the other end really.

Comment: What's the problem with using `'options' => array('100' => 100, '200' => 200, '300' => 300, '400' => 400, '500' => 500, '600' => 600)`? We don't see anything here that "needs" the tierX.

Answer (score 0):

Because the meta value is stored on the array form, the code should be

```
<?php 

    $donation_tier  = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_job_donation', false );
    $donation = "";
    if($donation_tier != null){
        foreach($donation_tier as $key => $donation_tier){
            if ($donation_tier === 'tier1') {
                $donation = "100";
            }
            else if ($donation_tier === 'tier2') {
                $donation = "200";
            }
            else if ($donation_tier === 'tier3') {
                $donation = "300";
            }
            else if ($donation_tier === 'tier4') {
                $donation = "400";
            }
            else if ($donation_tier === 'tier5') {
                $donation = "500";
            }
            else if ($donation_tier === 'tier6') {
                $donation = "600";
            } else {
                $donation = $donation_tier;
            }
        }
    }
?>

<?php do_action( 'single_job_listing_meta_end' ); ?>

<li class="meta-important">The successful applicant will need to pay a donation of £<?php echo $donation; ?>  plus an £50 standard fee to Horses 4 Homes upon completion.</li>
```